# Pass a tuple of integers to range() function

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a number is in an interval of numbers using

```py
if number in range(2010, 2020)
```

However I would like to store `(2010, 2020)` in a tuple with meaningful variable name:

```
VALID_YEARS = (2010, 2020)
if number in range(VALID_YEARS)
```

which returns an error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I know it's possible to

```py
valid_start_year = 2010
valid_end_year = 2020
if number in range(valid_start_year, valid_end_year)
```

but for me using a tuple would be more "concise".

Is it possible? How?

Comment: What's the point though? If all you're doing is checking if a number is between two other numbers, just do `valid_start_year <= number <= valid_end_year`. Creating a `range` object just for this purpose is silly.

Comment: Disagree @ddejohn, I like doing thins pythonic way. Through Grismars answer I just discovered unpacking operator which works for dicts as well. Even if the example is not complicated the use of the concept of what I was trying to do extends to more complicated ones,  which can in the future help me implementing  more concise/readable code.

Comment: Chained comparison is more "pythonic" than using a range object... a chained comparison is *much* clearer to the reader what you're doing -- this is an absolutely silly way to write code. There are legitimate use-cases for variable and keyword unpacking -- this is not one of them.

Comment: Strongly disagree. I prefer a "functional" way of programming. Using logic operators of course works and is fine in this extremely simple example, but range(beg, start) is stronger in that sense, it does only one thing, unlike using logic operators where programmer could mess up logic (< instead of <=, etc). Also I learned something new (very useful) and loved grismars solution. best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the unpacking operator:

```
VALID_YEARS = (2010, 2020)
number = 2015
if number in range(*VALID_YEARS):
    print('yep')
```

Similarly, you can also unpack dictionaries to serve as parameters to a function (for example), but you need the double star:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}


def fun(a, b):
    print(f'{a} and {b}')


fun(**d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware of the existence of this operator, very useful! I'll accept your answer as soon as stack allows me